# How can i find this complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

How can i find this complex integral?

$\int _{\Gamma} z^{i}dz$

where $\Gamma(t) =1-t^2+it, \quad -1 \leq t \leq 1$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $z^i$ is the multivalued function

$$\begin{align}
z^i=e^{i\log(z)}&=e^{i(\log(|z|)+i\text{Arg}(z)+i2n\pi)}\\\\
&=e^{i\log(|z|)-\text{Arg}(z)-2n\pi}
\end{align}$$

where $n$ is any integer and where $-\pi< \text{Arg}(z)\le \pi$ is the principal value of the argument of $z$.  If we choose the principal branch of the logarithm to define $z^i$, then $z^i$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-\infty,0)$ and we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_\Gamma z^i\,dz&=\left.\left(\frac{z^{i+1}}{i+1}\right)\right|_{-i}^{i}\\\\
&=\frac{i^{i+1}-(-i)^{i+1}}{i+1}\\\\
&=\frac{e^{(i+1)\log(i)}-e^{(i+1)\log(-i)}}{i+1}\\\\
&=\frac{e^{(i+1)i\pi/2}-e^{-(i+1)i\pi/2}}{i+1}\\\\
&=\frac{ie^{-\pi/2}+ie^{\pi/2}}{i+1}\\\\
&=(1+i)\cosh(\pi/2)
\end{align}$$

and we are done!